# HTML string not binded with angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

```
<!DOCTYPE html
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "<input type='text' value='here'>";
});
</script>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example includes the "angular-sanitize.js",
which has functions for removing potentially dangerous tokens from the HTML.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to angular as well. I could not bind the html text to the angular view. Any suggestions could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud use $sce.trustAsHtml() like this

```
$scope.myText=$sce.trustAsHtml("<input type='text' value='here'>")
```

[Like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odvsLn3s/)

but then you cannot bind scope variables to your html so best way is writing a directive which can be replace with ng-bind-html-unsafe
something like

```
.directive('bindUnsafeHtml', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
              // watch the 'bindUnsafeHtml' expression for changes
              return scope.$eval(attrs.bindUnsafeHtml);
            },
            function(value) {
              // when the 'bindUnsafeHtml' expression changes
              // assign it into the current DOM
              element.html(value);

              // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
              // scope.
              // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
              // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
}])
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmu4qy03/)